# How to assign multiple possible types in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've got a simple react component where I have input which should be able to become one of to types. I don't know how to do this, if it's possible. If not what would be a good practices of archiving the same effect?

```
import * as React from 'react'

interface Checkboxes {
  label?: string
  items: any //should be either string[] or CheckboxItem[]
}

interface CheckboxItem {
  text: string
  checked?: boolean
}

export default function Checkboxes(props: Checkboxes) {
  const {
    label,
    items,
  } = props

  return (
    <fieldset className="checkboxes">
      {label && <legend>{label}</legend>}
      {items.map((item, index) => <label key={index}><input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={item.checked} />{item.text}</label>)}
    </fieldset>
  )
}
```

`
As i tried union types the following error appears on the map function:

```
(property) Array<T>.map: (<U>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: CheckboxItem, index: number, array: CheckboxItem[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])
Calls a defined callback function on each element of an array, and returns an array that contains the results.

@param callbackfn — A function that accepts up to three arguments. The map method calls the callbackfn function one time for each element in the array.

@param thisArg — An object to which the this keyword can refer in the callbackfn function. If thisArg is omitted, undefined is used as the this value.

This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '(<U>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: CheckboxItem, index: number, array: CheckboxItem[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2349)
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `items: any //should be either string[] or CheckboxItem[]`

Using a union type.

## Example

```
interface Checkboxes {
  label?: string
  items: string[] | CheckboxItem[]
}
```

Comment: I tried this, however I get an error message in the `items.map()` function.

Comment: @pgalle is it possible the error message isn't complaining about the Array type? Think about `.map(item => {})`, what type is `item`?

Comment: @stealththeninja item is of type string I'd say.

Comment: @pgalle does the compiler know that? ;) My Typescript is rusty but I think you can cast it: `.map(<string>item => {})`. Type `any` is permissive which is why I'm guessing you didn't see an error before.

Comment: @stealththeninja if I cast item to type string, then the component wont work when using my custom type `CheckboxItem`

Comment: @pgalle does `CheckboxItem` extend the `string` type? If not, how can items actually be either type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218012/discussion-between-pgalle-and-stealththeninja).